# How to make my URL look like this...?

Tags: url

I was wondering how to make my website's url look from:

```
some_folder/?d=some_file.php
```

to..

```
/?d=some_file.php
```

Comment: Windows tags?...

Comment: We will need more info about your set-up. Which web server are you using?. How is it configured?. Please edit the question and add as much information as possible.

Comment: This will most likely get a better answer over at superuser ( http://superuser.com/ ). - a sister site to this one.

Comment: This is not really related to Ubuntu directly at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Apache, check out mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Apache web server, [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) is a guide for beginners.

Basically you'll need these entries in the `.htaccess` file in your website root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some_folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Also you should turn off rewrite in `/some_folder/` otherwise multiple rewrites can occur. So you'll need another `.htaccess` file in `/some_folder/` with:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

The above will have the effect of reaching all files in `/some_folder/` as they were in `/`. E.g.:

```
/index.html -> /some_folder/index.html
```

Notes:

- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) should be enabled to be able to rewrite URLs.
- Make sure you do not create conflicts (e.g. identical file in both root and `/some_folder/`).
- You need to allow `FileInfo` [override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for your website directory to be able to use `.htaccess` files.
- Also using `.htaccess` files is a performance hit on web servers. See: [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) how to avoid it.